# C++ and opencv3.4 and lib that uses also opencv but other version as a dependency

Tags: c++, opencv, dll

I am confused about how to use libraries. how do I link the folowing properly?
What do I have to do in Visual Studio?

```
myprogram ---> opencv 3.4
          |
          ---> 3rd party lib  ---> opencv 2.x
                              |
                              ---> many other libs(tbb, boost, ...)
```

I am just confused about what todo with the 2 opencv's.

Thanks!

Comment: I would avoid this situation if possible. I mean recompile the 3rd party library if you can. Otherwise  you may want to restrict yourself to the same version of opencv that they are using.

Comment: Also you likely have to use the same compiler version that they are using for the 3rd party library. Remember that Visual Studio 2015 and 2017 are binary compatible but no other versions of Visual Studio are compatible with each other. And its not safe to mix debug and release. Meaning all dlls must be the same configuration of your application.

Comment: You mean recompiling the 3rd party with opencv3.4 and also using opencv3.4 myself?

Comment: ***You mean recompiling the 3rd party with opencv3.4 and also using opencv3.4 myself?*** That would be preferred. Make sure you do that with the same compiler that you use for your application.